# ALL Android Apps Randomly Crashing?

Tags: applications, crashes, troubleshooting

Recently my Galaxy Grand Prime has been acting weird. All of the apps, including settings, facebook, and youtube have been randmly crashing. I haven't done anything to it like rooting or factory resetting it. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Sometimes it can happen due to memory failures when the memory becomes read-only, but I only noticed on Huawei, Sony and LG devices, never noticed that on Samsung devices. Try factory resetting first and see if it helps.

Comment: I agree... Had a similar isue with HTC One, which was resolved successfully only after factory reset and data wipe-out.

Comment: I did a factory reset, and it didn't seem to help. I thought it might be a gesture on the sensor, turns out that ain't it.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a faulty RAM or some other hardware component like flash storage or CPU. But it does not seem to matter what part is faulty, as on phone, you usually can't simply replace one of them.